# Getting .on() to work with a dynamically created HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange, conditional-statements

I'm having some trouble getting the functionality I want out of the `.on()` method in jQuery. I'm trying to get it to start checking for changes to an HTML element that doesn't exist when the page first loads. Unfortunately I couldn't turn up any examples like this on Google or Stack Overflow.

Here's my situation: I have some dropdown menus and some text boxes in HTML, and I want to show the the text boxes only if a particular option is selected from the dropdown menu (the 'other' option).

I have this working just fine using `.on('change')` with a function that shows or hides the text box. That code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#partialOther_1").hide(); //textbox id = partialOther_1
$("#partial_1" ).on('change', function() { //dropdown id = partial_1
  var partVar1 = $(this).val();
  if(partVar1 > 0) {
    $("#partialOther_1").show();
  }
  else {
    $("#partialOther_1").hide();
  }
});
```

The problem is that I want to accomplish the same thing for another dropdown/text box pair that only appears in the HTML if something from the first dropdown menu is selected. I was trying the code below, but the I think problem is with the second condition. When the script runs it evaluates to false and I'm not sure of the best way to re-check the condition and get the `.on()` method to continue 'listening' if it is true. I'd prefer not to use `setInterval()` if at all possible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var partVar2 = 0
   $("#partial_1" ).on('change', function() {
     var partVar2 = $(this).val();
     if(partVar2 > 0) {
       $("#brokerOther_1").hide();
      }
   });
   if(partVar2>0) { //'broker' only exists in HTML  if partial_1 >0
     $("#broker" ).on('change', function() { 
     var brokerVar = $(this).val();
     if(brokerVar == 4) {
       $("#brokerOther_1").show();
     }
     else {
       $("#brokerOther_1").hide();
     }
     });
   }
});
```

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Please provide your HTML code, and what version of jQuery are you using? Going to take a look.

Comment: @kehrk Using 1.10.2 (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js). Thanks!

Comment: How about your HTML code?

Comment: @kehrk The tricky part with the HTML is that the dynamic element is created not by my code but by a GUI I am using to create a survey. I'll try to copy the relavant parts into this post ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the condition when the event is bound, you should check it when the event happens instead:

```
$("#broker").on('change', function() {
  if (partVar2 > 0) {
    var brokerVar = $(this).val();
    if(brokerVar == 4) {
      $("#brokerOther_1").show();
    } else {
      $("#brokerOther_1").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

If the element doesn't exist from start, you want to use a delegate, i.e. bind the event to some parent element that does exist, and use a second selector to specify where to listen to events from:

```
$(document.body).on('change', "#broker", function() {
```

If possible, use an element closer to the element than the body element, so that it has to check as few events as possible.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this now. The reason I didn't think this would work though is that I thought if I try to call a method on an element that dosn't exist yet (broker in this case) the script would fail - is that wrong?

Comment: @cerpintaxt: I got the impression that the element does exist, but it's hidden. Are you adding elements dynamically to the page?

Comment: Yes, sorry I realize now that my post was unclear. The element 'broker' only exists in the html code if something is selected from 'partial_1' Editing post now.

Comment: @cerpintaxt: When you wan't to use a delegate to bind the event. I added code above.